# Plaid account_id across logins

Tags: plaid

I accept and understand why the ‘’’account_id’’’ may change for a given account returned by Plaid. (Frustrating but understand why it happens)

My question is about situations where the account is associated with multiple credentials at the financial institution.

For instance, take a joint savings account. If two individuals attempt to connect their “bank accounts” where each has a separate checking account but they have a joint savings account, **will the ‘’’account_id’’’ for the joint savings account be the same across each link flow?**

Or is it the case that since the credentials used to connect the financial accounts are different, then the ‘’’account_id’’’ will always be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `account_id` as an identifier is persistent only within the context of a specific access token. The `account_id` across two different Items will not be the same, even if the underlying account is the same.

Comment: You say that, and that is what the docs say, but only now starting to settle in. Thanks